# Need help with understanding this script file

Tags: bitcoin-core

Here is an image of txt file. I had asked someone to help get some bitcoin out and they sent me this code with a price tag of 12$ But I have no idea what its used for as they have not responded. Any help is grateful thanks
[image: Script Text file]

Comment: They're trolling you. This is just a part of Bitcoin Core's source code.

Answer (score 0):

> they sent me this code with a price tag of 12$

You, or anyone, can download that code for free from https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin

There is no fee or price, it is free of charge, $0

> I have no idea what its used for

As Pieter said, it is the source-code for a computer program, a Bitcoin wallet called "bitcoin core". You use the source code with a program called a C-compiler to create a program that you can then use. But you can just download the already compiled program from the appropriate website. The source code and the compiled bitcoin-core program isn't really suitable for anyone new to Bitcoin. The compiled program is a "wallet" that provides a way of controlling an amount of Bitcoin that you have obtained by  buying from an exchange or by selling something for bitcoin.

It doesn't generate money.

> I had asked someone to help get some bitcoin out

If you already have some Bitcoin, you probably already have the means to get it out (convert it into another currency, use it to buy something). You would have a wallet or an account with an exchange or something similar.

If this doesn't make much sense to you, it is quite possible you have been tricked and don't really have any Bitcoin to get out.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback everyone. Helps me understand. They just sent another email stating If I pay 12$ the other part of this code can be used to get any kind of  wallet info and withdraw it. My intention was never that I said. I have the link for YouTube if anyone wants to see the scammer . My other question , is this guy using this code and a c-compiler as you say to control or withdraw blockchain coin out?

Thanks everyone

Comment: @Lisa: This guy is using this source code simply to confuse his victims. He doesn't need this source code for anything, neither do you.